# How update ListBox when ItemsSource changed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have buttons "ADD" and "DEL", but "DEL" does not work. What is wrong?

count in my `ObservableCollection<User>` was changed but ListBox does not

sample project: https://github.com/Veselov-Dmitry/MyQuestion

view:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="ADD"
            Command="{Binding AddUsers_OASUCommand}"
            CommandParameter="">
    </Button>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Users_OASU}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Login}" />
                    <Button Content="DEL"
                            Command="{Binding DelUsers_OASUCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Content,                                                     
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor , 
                                    AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}">
                        <Button.DataContext>
                            <local:ViewModel />
                        </Button.DataContext>
                    </Button>
                </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

I set datacontext in constructor MainView

viewvmodel:

```
class ViewModel
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<User> Users_OASU{get; set;}                
    public ICommand AddUsers_OASUCommand{get; set;} 
    public ICommand DelUsers_OASUCommand{get; set;} 

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Users_OASU = new ObservableCollection<User>(GetUsers());

        AddUsers_OASUCommand = new Command<object>(arg => AddUsers_OASUMethod());
        DelUsers_OASUCommand = new Command<object>(arg => DelUsers_OASUMethod(arg));
    }

    private void DelUsers_OASUMethod(object arg)
    {
        User find = Users_OASU.Where(x => x.Login == (arg as User).Login).FirstOrDefault();
        Users_OASU.Remove(find);
    }

    private void AddUsers_OASUMethod()
    {
        Users_OASU.Add(new User("52221", "John X."));
    }

    private List<User> GetUsers()
    {
        List<User> list = new List<User>();
        list.Add(new User("52222", "John W."));
        list.Add(new User("52223", "John Z."));
        list.Add(new User("52224", "John A."));
        list.Add(new User("52225", "John M."));
        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"count in my ObservableCollection was changed but ListBox does not" - you have multiple instances of ViewModel, count was changed, but not in the collection which is displayed

you need to setup DataTemplate correctly to avoid that

first, each Button will get User object for DataContext (it will be provided by ListBox from ItemsSource). You mustn't declare new `<Button.DataContext>`

second, `DelUsers_OASUCommand` is declared in a ViewModel class, it is accessible on ListBox level, from DataContext. Change binding path accordingly.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <WrapPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Login}" />
        <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.DelUsers_OASUCommand,
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Content, 
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"
                Content="DEL" />
    </WrapPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

additionally I would change `DelUsers_OASUMethod` to accept User as argument

```
private void DelUsers_OASUMethod(object arg)
{
    Users_OASU.Remove(arg as User);
}
```

and pass CommandParameter like this:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding Path=.}"
```

or the same, but shorter:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding}"
```